# How to convert one digit of a number from one base to another?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say that I have a number $a$ in base $b$ and I want to convert that number to base $c$. Since I'm working with huge numbers that computers have a difficult time processing at once I'm trying to split the computation into pieces.

If I use base 10 as $b$ and base 26 (English letters) as $c$:

```
Base 10        Base 26
----------------------
25             p
150            5k 
7429624        g6iek
```

**My question is:** how do I get only the specific digit of number $a$ in base $c$ without converting the whole number into base $c$?

As an example: how do I get the $4$th digit of number 7429624 in base 26? The answer is `n` (taken from the table above).

Comment: Let `a % b` be the minimum positive integer such that $a \equiv (a % b) \pmod {b}$. If so, if the number is `a` and you want to get the `b`th digit from right (counting from `0`, so ones place is `b=0`) in base `c`, the formula is: $$\left\lfloor \frac{a}{c^b} \right\rfloor \text{ % } c$$ I will put an explanation of this in my answer, if I have time to write one.

Comment: Also, your table is incorrect. $7429624$ in base $26$ is `g6lek`.

Comment: Furthermore, $150$ in base $26$ is $5k$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Sorry about that. I fixed my table now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given you a formula in the comments, but I think it is easier to show this as a process.

We have:

$$7429624_{10}=??????????_{26}$$

You want to find the $4^{\text{th}}$ digit from left. However, it's much easier to find digits counting from the right. In this case, we want the $2^{\text{nd}}$ digit from right. To find this digit, we first want to move it to the ones place. We do this by dividing by $26$ to move the decimal point one place to the left:

$$\frac{7429624_{10}}{26_{10}}=?????????.?_{26}$$

Now, the second question mark from right is in the ones place. To get rid of the fraction part, take the floor of both sides:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{7429624_{10}}{26_{10}} \right\rfloor=?????????_{26}$$

Now, we want the ones place of this right-hand number. Finding the ones place is easy because to find the ones place of any number $a$ in base $c$, you just to $a \% c$, which is a very common operation in programming languages. (I assume, since you are using a computer, that you are programming.) Therefore, we just do the $\% 26$ to both sides to find the ones digit of the right side:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{7429624_{10}}{26_{10}} \right\rfloor \% 26=?_{26}$$

Now, $\left\lfloor \frac{7429624_{10}}{26_{10}} \right\rfloor \% 26$ is $14$. Since this is over $9$, we need to convert it to the $14-9=5^{\text{th}}$ letter, which is `e`. Note that the answer is not `n` since the whole number is actually `g6lek`, not `mzlng`.